# docker-compose for orthanc

Tags: docker, docker-compose, orthanc-server

I'm trying to replicate a command for docker-compose for orthanc that I previously ran as a Docker command in the command line and I'm having some trouble translating it

The docker command is:

```
docker run -p 4242:4242 -p 8042:8042 -e OSIMIS_WEB_VIEWER1_PLUGIN_ENABLED=true --network=host --rm -v /orthanc.json:/etc/orthanc/orthanc.json:ro -v /tmp/orthanc-db/:/var/lib/orthanc/db/ osimis/orthanc
```

How can I translate this for docker-compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  orthanc:
    image: osimis/orthanc
    ports:
      - 4242:4242
      - 8042:8042
    environment:
      OSIMIS_WEB_VIEWER1_PLUGIN_ENABLED: "true"
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - /orthanc.json:/etc/orthanc/orthanc.json:ro
      - /tmp/orthanc-db/:/var/lib/orthanc/db/
```

Worth noting that the `--rm` flag can't really be replicated (as far as I know).

Also `true` in the environment variable must enclosed in quotes like `"true"` to prevent it from being a yaml boolean value.

Once that's in a `docker-compose.yml` you can run it with `docker-compose run orthanc` or `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Thankyou!! Little things around the syntax have been holding me up forever!